# GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx fails due To an invalid parameter

Tags: winapi, console, realbasic, realstudio

I am trying to call the [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from a console application. If it matters, the application is a 32 bit application running on 64 bit Windows 7. The language is RealBasic.

I believe I have defined all the structures correctly, and the buffer output handle works for every other API function that is being called:

```vb
  Declare Function GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx Lib "Kernel32" (cHandle As Integer, ByRef info As CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX) As Boolean
  Declare Function GetLastError Lib "Kernel32" () As Integer
  Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "Kernel32" (hIOStreamType As Integer) As Integer

  Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
  Dim stdHandle As Integer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

  Dim err As Integer
  Dim info As CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX

  If GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdHandle, info) Then
    Break
  Else
    err = GetLastError  //Always 87, Invalid parameter
    Break
  End If
```

Structures:

```vb
Structure CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX
  cbSize As Integer
  dwSize As COORD
  CursorPosition As COORD
  Attribute As UInt16
  srWindow As SMALL_RECT
  MaxWindowSize As COORD
  PopupAttributes As UInt16
  FullScreenSupported As Boolean
  ColorTable(15) As UInt32


Structure COORD
  X As UInt16
  Y As UInt16


Structure SMALL_RECT
  Left As UInt16
  Top As UInt16
  Right As UInt16
  Bottom As UInt16
```

I've gone over this 20 times and nothing looks wrong to me. I've used the COORD and SMALL_RECT structures many times before, so I don't think I made any translation errors on them. The CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX structure, however, is seeing its first use by me here, and I sense that the error lies somewhere in my translation of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the cbSize parameter of the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` before you send it in.  `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` will check that it is the correct size and that's why it's returning an invalid parameter.

So before the call to `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` add:

```
info.cbSize = 96
```

Or better yet Real Basic does allow you to access the size of the [structure](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Structure):

`info.cbSize = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx.Size`

Which should handle the calculation for you.

Comment: Well yes, but **don't hardcode the size**! That's what compilers are for.

Comment: Interestingly, I had already tried this and I *didn't* hard code the size. If I use `96` (hard coded) then the function succeeds. If I add up all the members of the struct, as I defined it, the size is **93**. So, it would seem that there is an error in the structure definition somewhere.

Comment: @Amazed - there's no error it's due to structure alignment - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71kf49f1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: So, should I detect whether I'm running in WoW64 and explicitly use `96` if so? Using `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX.Size` returns `93` under WoW64.

Comment: @Amazed, no the size shouldn't change under WoW64 - it'll still be 96.  If `CONSOLE.SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX.Size` is returning 93 then it's laying it out incorrectly.  Try using the StructureAlignment attribute to set the alignment to 8, which I believe is what Windows uses.